# How to get a string equivalent of an encoded string?

Tags: python, encoding, decoding

Consider the following Python code:

```
payload = """{"id": "866425038985380","ts": "2020-05-07T13:16:51.350Z"}"""
ascii_message = payload.encode('ascii')
encoded_payload = base64.b64encode(ascii_message)
string_payload = str(encoded_payload)
print(string_payload)
print(type(encoded_payload))
```

When I print the lines above, my output is:

```
b'eyJpZCI6ICI4NjY0MjUwMzg5ODUzODAiLCJ0cyI6ICIyMDIwLTA1LTA3VDEzOjE2OjUxLjM1MFoifQ=='
<class 'bytes'>
```

Is it possible to get a string equivalent of the encoded result? In particular, how can I get this:

```
'eyJpZCI6ICI4NjY0MjUwMzg5ODUzODAiLCJ0cyI6ICIyMDIwLTA1LTA3VDEzOjE2OjUxLjM1MFoifQ=='
```

I'd like to set that to a new variable without the `b` in front and for it to type string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Comment: `string_payload = base64.b64encode(ascii_message).decode('ascii')`

Comment: The `b"..."` is not actually in the data. (Take its `len()` if you doubt that.) What you are seeing is Python's technical representation of a bytestring, which is a bunch of 8-bit quantities. They differ from Python strings which are always Unicode, and the `b` is to show you which is which, much as `2.0` shows you that you are dealing with a float.  Use the bytestring as is. Binary files, network protocols and encryption libraries will happily accept it because it is what they are expecting.

Comment: @BoarGules , is there a way to retrieve just that bytestring then?

Comment: That *is* the bytestring. Just use it. By default Python displays bytestrings with a `b` prefix just as it displays lists with square brackets and commas. They are not really in the data either.